# Powershell: no output with script

Tags: powershell, memory, cpu

I am looking into a way that I can get the CPU and Memory usage from my servers but i'm not getting a output from this script, Is there something wrong with the way Write-Host is setup here? Any Help is appreciated

```
    Function Get-ADtop {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [String]$ComputerName,
    [String]$Sort = "none",  
    [String]$BaseDN = "OU=systems,DC=domain,DC=com",  # Edit Default Base DN
    [String]$SampleTime = 2
)
If ($ComputerName) {
    $Computers = $ComputerName
} else {
    $Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $BaseDN -EA SilentlyContinue | % {$_.Name}
}
$DataSet = @()
$Targets = @()
ForEach ($Comp in $Computers) {
    If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Comp -Count 1 -Quiet -TimeToLive 1 -EA SilentlyContinue) {
        If (!(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Comp win32_OperatingSystem -EA SilentlyContinue)) { break }
        $Targets += $Comp
    }
}
$CompCount = $Computers | Measure-Object | % {$_.Count}
$DeadCount = $CompCount - ($Targets | Measure-Object | % {$_.Count})
If (!($DeadCount -eq 0)) {
    Write-Host "`n$DeadCount unavailable computers removed"
}
Write-Host "`nGathering realtime CPU/MEM/DISK Usage data from $CompCount computers..."
ForEach ($Comp in $Targets) {
    $proc = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Comp -class win32_processor -EA SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average | % {$_.Average / 100}).ToString("P")
    $mem = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Comp win32_OperatingSystem -EA SilentlyContinue 
    $mem = (($mem.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $mem.FreePhysicalMemory) / $mem.TotalVisibleMemorySize).ToString("P")
    $disk = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Comp -class Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType=3" -EA SilentlyContinue 
    $disk = (($disk.Size - $disk.FreeSpace) / $disk.Size).ToString("P")
    $Info = [pscustomobject]@{
        'Computer' = $Comp
        'CPU Usage' = $proc
        'MEM Usage' = $mem
        'Disk Usage' = $disk
    }
    $DataSet += Add-Member -InputObject $Info -TypeName Computers.CPU.Usage -PassThru    
}
Switch ($Sort) {
    "none" { $DataSet }
    "CPU" { $DataSet | Sort-Object -Property "CPU Usage" -Descending }
    "MEM" { $DataSet | Sort-Object -Property "MEM Usage" -Descending }
    "DISK" { $DataSet | Sort-Object -Property "DISK Usage" -Descending }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script fails as is on a system with more than one fixed disk.  To fix this, I modified your line 33 to iterate through each disk.  This error was a terminating error, which is why PowerShell wouldn't give you an output before.

It seems to work with no issues now.

```
$disk = $disk | % {($($_.Size) - $($_.FreeSpace)) / $($d_.Size).ToString("P")}

>Gathering realtime CPU/MEM/DISK Usage data from 1 computers...

 Computer  CPU Usage MEM Usage Disk Usage        
 --------  --------- --------- ----------        
 localhost 14.00 %   27.64 %   {62.91 %, 34.90 %}
```

Comment: May I ask how you are executing the script?

Comment: Copied and paste it into the ISE.  On my system, I've got two Hard drives, by the way.

Comment: Do you still not get any output after making the change I showed you?  If so, start simply by running this against localhost as I did `Get-ADtop -ComputerName localhost`.

Comment: I was running it against the wrong hostname. I was logged in remotely on a different server. It works fine on the server which has multiple disks but it doesnt display the Disk usage on my local machine with only 1 Physical drive. With error: `Gathering realtime CPU/MEM/DISK Usage data from 1 computers...
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At 33 char:59`

Comment: How are you running it against your local machine?  Like what is the precise literal exact command you're running?

Comment: Load the script into ISE and then running Get-ADtop -ComputerName localhost. I do have 3 network Drives, maybe that is the culprit

Comment: I didnt give this much thought but the network drives are DriveType 4, The physical drives are DriveType 3. Script is set to query DriveType 3 not 4

Comment: Forget about the disk= part, what if you just run the WMI query against your system? You really should be seeing some kind of output here

Comment: Get-WmiObject -class Win32_LogicalDisk -computername localhost -filter "DriveType=3" -EA SilentlyContinue Displays the results successfully